# How do I use ItemFilters with eBay::API::Simple::Finding?

Tags: perl, ebay-api

I am playing with getting sold items from ebay using [eBay::API::Simple::Finding](https://metacpan.org/pod/eBay::API::Simple::Finding) and I want to use ItemFilters but I can't see where they go. 
In particular I am looking to use the item filters

```
(itemFilter.name = SoldItemsOnly, itemFilter.value = true)
and
(itemFilter.name = Condition, itemFilter.value = Used)
```

I tried just including directly with the following here:

```
keywords => '"princess cut", "diamond ring", -"14k*"', 
Condition => 'Sold',
SoldItemsOnly => 'true', 
sortOrder => 'PricePlusShippingHighest'
```

I have been on it quite a while and whilst I am sure it is somehow quite straight forward, I just can't seem to get it

```
use eBay::API::Simple::Finding;

my $api = eBay::API::Simple::Finding->new( {
   appid   => 'APIKEY',
   siteid  => 'EBAY-AU',
} );

$api->execute( 
    'findCompletedItems', { 
    keywords => '"princess cut", "diamond ring", -"14k*"',  
    sortOrder => 'PricePlusShippingHighest',
    } 
);

if ( $api->has_error() ) {
   die "Call Failed:" . $api->errors_as_string();
}

my $dom  = $api->response_dom();
my $hash = $api->response_hash();
```

Any help is very appreciated,

As for what I am seeing?
The sort is working, the search by keywords is working, but the itemfilters are not working, so it is returning new & used items that have completed, whether sold or unsold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the [eBay API docs about `findCompletedItems`](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/callref/types/ItemFilter.html) shows that you need to use child elements for `ItemFilter`s. There is [a sample](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/callref/findCompletedItems.html#Samples) that shows this nicely [(link)](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/callref/Samples/findCompletedItems_basic_in_xml_xml.txt).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<findCompletedItemsRequest xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">
   <keywords>Garmin nuvi 1300 Automotive GPS Receiver</keywords>
   <categoryId>156955</categoryId>
   <itemFilter>
      <name>Condition</name>
      <value>3000</value>
   </itemFilter>
   <itemFilter>
      <name>FreeShippingOnly</name>
      <value>true</value>
   </itemFilter>
   <itemFilter>
      <name>SoldItemsOnly</name>
      <value>true</value>
   </itemFilter>
   <sortOrder>PricePlusShippingLowest</sortOrder>
   <paginationInput>
      <entriesPerPage>2</entriesPerPage>
      <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
   </paginationInput>
</findCompletedItemsRequest>
```

Looking at the source code of the [eBay::API::Simple::Finding](https://metacpan.org/source/TKEEFER/eBay-API-Simple-0.29/lib/eBay/API/Simple/Finding.pm#L10) module we can see that it uses [XML::Simple](http://p3rl.org/XML::Simple) to construct requests. While in general `XML::Simple` is discouraged, we will have to work with it.

Taking a deeper look at the docs for the `ItemFilter` shows that we can provide one `<itemFilter>` block per filter. That implies that multiple ones are treated as AND automatically.

To make a single item with the way XML::Simple get set up in the API module, we just need a hashref.

```perl
{
    itemFilter => {
        name => 'Condition',
        value => 3000,
    },
}
```

will become

```xml
<itemFilter>
  <name>Condition</name>
  <value>3000</value>
</itemFilter>
```

To get several, we need an array reference behind the `itemFilter` key.

```perl
{
    itemFilter => [
        {
            name => 'Condition',
            value => 3000,
        },
        {
            name => 'FreeShippingOnly',
            value => 'true',
        },
    ],
}
```

This produces this XML.

```xml
<itemFilter>
  <name>Condition</name>
  <value>3000</value>
</itemFilter>
<itemFilter>
  <name>FreeShippingOnly</name>
  <value>true</value>
</itemFilter>
```

So far so good. We can easily hack that into the API module call. Instead of executing the call directly, I have prepared it, and then called the [private method `_get_request_body`](https://metacpan.org/source/TKEEFER/eBay-API-Simple-0.29/lib/eBay/API/Simple/Finding.pm#L282), which uses XML::Simple to form and return the request body string. That's neat to check if the request will look ok. I figured that out by reading the code, starting at the one I lined above, and working my way towards the base class, which provides `execute`.

```perl
use eBay::API::Simple::Finding;

my $api = eBay::API::Simple::Finding->new( {
   appid   => 'APIKEY',
   siteid  => 'EBAY-AU',
} );

$api->prepare(
    'findCompletedItems',
    {
        keywords   => '"princess cut", "diamond ring", -"14k*"',
        sortOrder  => 'PricePlusShippingHighest',
        itemFilter => [
            {
                name  => 'SoldItemsOnly',
                value => 'true',
            },
            {
                name  => 'Condition',
                value => 'Used',
            },
        ],
    }
);

print $api->_get_request_body;
```

Here's the XML that comes out.

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<findCompletedItemsRequest xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">
  <itemFilter>
    <name>SoldItemsOnly</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </itemFilter>
  <itemFilter>
    <name>Condition</name>
    <value>Used</value>
  </itemFilter>
  <keywords>&quot;princess cut&quot;, &quot;diamond ring&quot;, -&quot;14k*&quot;</keywords>
  <sortOrder>PricePlusShippingHighest</sortOrder>
</findCompletedItemsRequest>
```

It doesn't matter that it' not indented nicely. It is clear that the filters are there.

Since I don't have an API key I cannot run this myself, but I am pretty sure it's going to work.

Comment: For some reason the syntax highlighting markup doesn't work properly in my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much, I will check it out and see if I can get it working with that, will let you know

Comment: @ArseneWenger no problem. :) Sometimes it just helps to read the documentation and also to dive into the code. You can learn a lot that way. Welcome to Stack Overflow and the Perl tag, btw. This was a great first question.

Comment: *"For some reason the syntax highlighting markup doesn't work properly in my answer"* Syntax highlighting reverts to the default within quote blocks. See [*Is there a way to provide a syntax hint for code within a blockquote?*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323566/is-there-a-way-to-provide-a-syntax-hint-for-code-within-a-blockquote). I hope I've fixed it satisfactorily.

Comment: @Borodin thanks. I'm not sure. I don't see XML highlighting on the last block. The first one was supposed to be a quote because I copied it verbatim from that documentation. I thought switching around between Perl and XML would be enough, but I didn't understand why it would not do take for the last few code blocks.

Comment: @simbabque: I'm sorry. That last block wasn't highlighted properly because I didn't mark it. It's fixed. It doesn't help that the CSS uses very grey pastel colours. I'm tempted to think that Stack Exchange know that their highlighting is poor and are trying to do as little as possible to make its mistakes readable. I always try to start extended answers with `
<!-- language-all: lang-none -->` so that I can choose my own highlighting. Having XML in all-black is much better than highlighting it badly as Perl!

Comment: Cheers @Borodin. I owe you another pint. :)

Comment: @simbabque: Do you know Imperial gallons? They're better than US gallons. Generally less fizzy and better-tasting :)

Comment: @Borodin we like our beer very fizzy and with a lot of foam over here. And of course in liters.

Comment: @simbabque: Eww! Fizzy and light like *Budweiser*? I can't drink even lemonade because the fizz *hurts*. I think I'm one of a small market who can't cope with any carbonation at all, and have to pour my beer from a height and wait for ten minutes! Oh, and UK gallons are about 4.5 litres, whereas a US gallon comes to 3.8 litres :)

Comment: @borodin I see. Well German beer doesn't work from pitchers or if it's too large. We have Pilsener mostly, which is not like your English stuff. But I prefer Guinness. mst is fond of dark Hefeweizen when he comes to Germany though. ;-)

Comment: @simbabque: We don't have pitchers either, although I wish we did. It's mostly pints by metred tap. The government tried to enforce metric units, and there were grocers arrested for selling by the pound, but they gave up and now we're a mixture. Supermarkets play with the measurements to suit themselves, as they always will. Guinness has no fizz from the tap, only a head, so I often resort to that over a fizzy ale. "mst"? You mean **mso**?     Ah! *Dunkelweizen*!

Comment: @Borodin I meant the Perl developer [mst](https://metacpan.org/author/MSTROUT). _Dunkelweizen_ is exactly what he calls it, but we call it _Dunkles Hefeweizen_ because the yeast in it is important to us. You need to shake the bottle when it's almost empty to get the remaining yeast out and pour it into the glass. Some people roll it, others leave it laying on the sides too.